# The different use RedisTemplate execute() and opsFpr*()

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

Use Spring operate redis, the different RedisTemplate's execute() and opsFor*()?

Answer (score 0):

[Reference document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.4.0.RC1/reference/html/redis.html)

According to this document, there are two components: Low-Level Abstractions and High-Level Abstractions.

1.execute() method is Low-Level Abstractions, for operating redis via RedisConnection;

2.opsFor*() methods is High-Level Abstractions, for providing friendly template classes, the underlay also use RedisConnection and execute().

In fact, those two methods is same.